GIS Stack Exchange - Login Unavailable (29 / 30 April 2024)
I have been trying to access the GIS Stack Exchange since yesterday 29 April 2024. When clicking the "Login" icon, I am directed to a page where I am told that Logging in is not available. Full site message below:

Login is not available
The feature you’re trying to use is currently unavailable.
The site is currently in read-only mode. You can still access all the questions, answers, and general knowledge goodness.
We’ll enable all features of the site as soon as possible.
XOXO,
The Stack Exchange Team

There is also a ribbon along the top of the page saying the site is read-only:

This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon. Visit our status page or search our recent meta posts on the topic for more info.

The site is still receiving questions and answers. Going to the "status" pages and there appears to be no outage.
I am located in Australia, is there a local outage?
UPDATE
I have tried logging in through Edge and was successful. Login failure appeard to be when I try login using Chrome.
UPDATE 2
Seems to have resolved itself, I left the browser open all day and on my return, I was relogged in.
This can be closed.

No repro here in UK, I can interact with the site, no issues. However, I'm already logged in through https://stackexchange.com/

Also: https://www.stackstatus.net/ shows no outages...

Just tried joining GIS using a new account/different browser via a different Google ID, again no repro.

Possibly related (or possibly not): Why is Stack Overflow preventing signup with an invalid password message when the password meets the specified requirements?

Updated the question. I am able to login using EDGE, but not Chrome.

I'm no coder, but since the browsers I've used are both Chrome-based, it makes me wonder if you've disabled (or an update has disabled) JavaScript or some other essential component (cookie settings...?).

Try clearing cookies and cached data in Chrome.
